# What does the 'primary address' mean about the interface

Tags: linux, sockets, udp

What does the primary address of interface mean?In my mind,there's only one address of one interface. Is this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can assign additional "secondary" or "alias" addresses to an interface.
For example, this interface has 3 addresses.  The primary is "127.0.0.1".

```
# ifconfig lo0
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 33648
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
        inet alias 192.168.1.200 netmask 0xffffffff
        inet alias 192.168.140.200 netmask 0xffffffff
```

This means that this interface can accept packets addressed to all three of those addresses.  It can also send using all three of those as it source address, but as *Unix Network Programming* says, you need to specifically bind to a secondary address as it will use the primary by default.

Why might you want to do this?  Some reasons are:

- You are changing a machine's IP address and want to accept traffic at
  the old address for some period of time (say waiting for DNS changes
  to propagate).
- You are using [anycasting](https://serverfault.com/questions/14985/what-is-anycast-and-how-is-it-helpful) or other High-Availability techniques where each
  machine has its own address and there this a "service address" that can
  move from machine to machine.
- Your machine is acting as a routing device.